# Python unittest, mock return_value to return different value for every call

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I want to test a method which has two queries on same model, and I want every query to return different results.

```
def method_to_test():
    qs1 = Order.objects.filter()
    qs2 = Order.objects.filter()

@mock.patch('Order.objects.filter')
def test_method_to_test(self, mock_qs):
     mock_qs.return_value = MagicMock(side_effect=[Order(id=1), Order(id=2)])
     method_to_test()
```

But the query is not returning `Order(id=1)` or `Order(id=2)` is returning an Mock object. How can I set the `side_effect` to return the objects I want.
I saw that is working to set the `side_effect` inside `@mock.patch` decorator but I want to do it inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mock_qs.side_effect = [Order(id=1), Order(id=2)]`